# Print lines using line-numbers stored in shell variable, using sed

Tags: bash, sed, variable

I have a tab file from, which I am extracting the column containing the row numbers I need to extract lines from another file. I got the line numbers with `cut -f` and I stored them into a variable `list`. I tried to use `sed` with the following:

```
$ list="2 5 7 10"
$ echo $list
2 5 7 10
$ sed -n "$list p" longText.txt 
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `5'
$ sed -n "${list}p" longText.txt 
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `5'
```

What is the error? What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place an echo before your `sed` command to see where n why you are going wrong.

One way to go, using the `sed` editor is:

```
# assuming default IFS
## based on Kusalananda's observations
set -f ;# disable globbing
list="2 5 7 10"
for i in $list;do
  echo "${i}p"
done | sed -nf - longText.txt

## or per Kusalanda method has a bug in it
## for empty list it generates wrong output
# printf '%sp\n' $list | sed -nf - lonxt.txt
```

Comment: This worked out of the box, thanks

Comment: Why the loop? If you rely on the shell splitting the string you may just as well use `printf '%sp\n' $list` and hope there are only sane words in the split up list.

Comment: As pointed by Stephane the printf method is buggy. If list were empty it prints the whole file
The loop does not suffer from this shortcoming.

Comment: @guest_7 It's not buggy if you fix it. `printf '%sp\n' "${list:-"q;"}"`  See also the other alternative at the end of [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/646744/116858)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you try to run a `sed` command that ooks like

```
2 5 7 10p
```

This obviously makes no sense to `sed`, so it complains.

Part of your issue is using a single string to hold many different items (the line numbers).  This is better done with an array. Each array element (line number) will then need to have a `p` inserted after it to make it a separate `sed` command.

For the numbers 2, 5, 7, and 10, you want a `sed` script that looks something like

```
2p; 5p; 7p; 10p;
```

or

```
2p;5p;7p;10p;
```

or

```
2p
5p
7p
10p
```

You can create a script like that rather easily from an array in `bash`:

```bsh
lines=( 2 5 7 10 )
printf '%sp\n' "${lines[@]:-"q;"}" | sed -n -f /dev/stdin longText.txt
```

This uses `printf` to create a `sed` script from the list of numbers, and feeds it to `sed` which reads it from standard input with `-f /dev/stdin`, and applies it to you file.

If the list is empty, the `printf` will emit a `sed` expression that does not do anything and then terminates `sed`.

---

If you *need* to use the numbers in a string, then you could convert that string into a valid `sed` script and apply it to your file like so:

```bsh
sed 's/[[:digit:]]\{1,\}/&p;/g' <<<"$list" | sed -n -f /dev/stdin longText.txt
```

Given the string `2 5 7 10`, this would generate the `sed` script `2p; 5p; 7p; 10p;` and then apply that to your file in a similar manner as above.

An empty list would not cause `sed` to output anything.

Comment: Thank you, this works with `( list )` but with the real thing, I get the same kind of error. The `p` is added only on the last entry so the rest looks like a command: `lines=$(cat fileWithNumbers.tsv | cut -f 1); $ printf '%sp\n' "${list[@]}" ` gives `... 9286 9287  9288p`.

Comment: @Gigiux See end of my answer. I added a bit.

Comment: @Gigiux Your attempt failed only because you created `list` as a string. I have added a bit that uses `list` as a string, but your initial attempt would have suceeded had you used `list=( $( cut -f ... ) )`.